# Function returning the highest value in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, function, for-loop

I am still having slight troubles with functions and arrays. I have created an array that has been filled with random numbers. I am trying to create a function that sets up the array and returns the highest value. I am not to sure on how to approach this but this and what I have written so far has not been able to compile.

```
namespace Task_1._13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            gettingMaximum(int i);
        }

        public int gettingMaximum(int i);
        {        
            int maximum = 0;
            int[] myArray = new int[10];
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            { 
                myArray[i] = rand.Next(19);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    maximum = myArray[i];
                else
                    if (myArray[i] < maximum) maximum = myArray[i];
                int result = i;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's what I have gotten so far. I am not very experienced in programming so help would be appreciated.

Comment: This will not compile, you cant have a function variable `int i`, and then try to re-declare it in the for loop

Comment: Please see: List<T>.Sort() -- simple solution.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx  -- This looks like homework.

Comment: It is Homework. I was ill for the lecture on Arrays so I am trying to teach myself. It's not going well...

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive You don't need to sort a list to get the max value, you only need to iterate it once.  If you don't want to write the method yourself `Max` in LINQ will do it for you.

Comment: If it is for homework, then do not try to use the `Max` function provided by LINQ, that will not teach you loops.

Comment: Think about the *meaning* of every statement. You are returning a "result". That makes sense. What is result set to? The index. Not the value, but the index. So automatically you know the program has to be wrong. At some point you're going to have to assign maximum to result if you're going to return result.

Comment: Not sure using LINQ for homework is helpful. There are more issues than your array with this code, for instance: your second 'for' loop only executes once; multiple uses of 'i', etc.

Comment: Singlestepping your code will make you understand it better, but first you need it to compile though.

Comment: There's a lot here that should be changed, so I won't address it all because it looks like you need more understanding at a base level, but here are two things that strike me instantly: Inside your loop, you check to see if i is equal to 0, and if it is, make it the maximum. You don't need to do this inside the loop. This will make the loop perform this check every iteration of the loop. Instead, set `maximum = myArray[0]` before the loop. The second is that you are returning your result inside of your loop. Think about how that will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if(myArray[i] > maximum)
           {
             maximum = myArray[i];
           }
        }
return maximum;
```

OR you can just use the [Max function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549329.aspx) like this

```
return myArray.Max();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the largest value, you can use `System.Linq` and use the `Max` function.

```
int largestValue = myArray.Max();
```

[Enunerable.Max Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
public int gettingMaximum();
{

int maximum = 0;
int[] myArray = new int[10];
Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = rand.Next(19);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            maximum = myArray[i];
        else
            if (myArray[i] > maximum) maximum = myArray[i];
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Updated w/ comments

```
namespace Task_1._13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // gettingMaximum(int i); This won't work because the int can't be declared while it's being passed into the method
            int i = 0; // You need to declare the i before you pass it to a method. Although look closely at your method and the reason you are passing in a value. Do you need it or use it?
            Console.WriteLine(gettingMaximum(i)); // I'm outputting the results to the screen so that you can verify that at least something happened
        }

        public static int gettingMaximum(int z)//; You don't need the semicolon here  
                                               // Also, I renamed this to z to demonstrate that you never use it. You could just as easily remove it
                                               // Also, this method must be marked static which is outside the scope of this question
        {
            int maximum = 0;
            int[] myArray = new int[10];
            Random rand = new Random();

            // This looks good. You create the array and loop through the items and set the value
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            { 
                myArray[i] = rand.Next(19);
            }

            // This code counts to 10. During each step, it compares the current step with 0. 
            // If the step (i) is 0, you set the maximum to to that value.
            // Otherwise, you see if the array value at that step is LESS than the current maximum, and if it is
            // you set the maximum to be that value. 
            //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            //{
            //    if (i == 0)
            //        maximum = myArray[i];
            //    else
            //        if (myArray[i] < maximum) maximum = myArray[i];
            //    int result = i;   // Here, you're actually setting the result to the current step number
            //    return result;   // I think you meant to set it to maximum, but you can leave it out completely and just return maximum. 
            //}

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    maximum = myArray[i];
                }
                else
                { // Since you have nested if's, i'm using braces to illustrate the paths of the branches
                    if (myArray[i] > maximum) // What i think you mean is, is the value at this item in the array MORE than my current maximum
                    {
                        maximum = myArray[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            return maximum;
        }
    }
}
```